# How to remove R.java from JavaDoc

Tags: java, android, eclipse, javadoc, r.java-file

I tried to generate Java-documentation using eclipse then previewed my JavaDocumenttation using the 'Preview attached JavaDoc in Browser' option.

All the auto generated android classes such as R.drawable are present. How can I remove them? Should I remove them?

[image]

Comment: Is Doxygen an option or are you tied to Javadoc?

Comment: @JRaymond Tied to Javadoc I think as my program is for a University project which specificity requests Java Documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Within eclipse, when I click generate Javadoc, it brings up a wizard, with the option to select which classes/packages I want generated, from which I exclude gen (which contains the R.java)

[image]

As for whether or not you should, I would recommend excluding the entire gen package/source folder as it isn't really relevant info for anyone reading your documentation

Comment: Thanks Surprised I didn't notice this first time.